# method not call from another class

Tags: ios, delegates, uipickerview

I am giving you the code i have problem to calling method of uipicker but the didnot called Please help me as soon as possible .
thanks in advance

I am giving you description of my project uipicker deligae method are not called 
        please help me
in `demosecondcontroller.m`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        StateList*objstatelist= [[StateList alloc]init];
        [objstatelist callingStatelist];
    });
});
StateList.m(nsobject)
-(void)callingStatelist{

    @try {
        CheckConnection*obj=[[CheckConnection alloc]init];
        UrlService*objurlservice= [[UrlService alloc]init];
        [objurlservice url];

        [obj internet ];
        if (obj.conection==true) {
            NSString* soapMessage=  @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetStateList xmlns='http://tempuri.org'><webreq>%@</webreq></GetStateList></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
            // create a url to your asp.net web service.
            NSURL *tmpURl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",objurlservice.urlstring]];

            // create a request to your asp.net web service.
            NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tmpURl];

            // add http content type - to your request
            [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            // add  SOAPAction - webMethod that is going to be called
            [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetStateList" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

            // count your soap message lenght - which is required to be added in your request
            NSString *msgLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];
            // add content length
            [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

            // set method - post
            [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            // set http request - body
            [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // establish connection with your request & here delegate is self, so you need to implement connection's methods
            NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

            // if connection is established
            if(con)
            {
                responseData=[[NSMutableData data] init];
                // here -> NSMutableData *myWebData; -> declared in .h file
            }
        }
        else{
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Smart24x7" message:@"Check your internet connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exeption%@",exception);
    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responseData = nil;

    responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;"
                                                               withString:@">"];
    responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;"
                                                               withString:@"<"];
    NSData* data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response%@",responseString);
    responcearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    parsar = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];
    [parsar setDelegate: (id)self];
    [parsar setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [parsar parse];


}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    elementValue= elementName;

    if ([elementValue isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {

        //        elementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [responcearray addObject:string];
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    DEMOSecondViewController*obj=[[DEMOSecondViewController alloc]init];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [obj get_Statelist_Responce:responcearray];
        });
    });

}
//in demosecondcontroller.m
-(void)get_Statelist_Responce:(NSArray*)responce_ArrayForstate
{
    stateListarray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    stateListarray=responce_ArrayForstate;
    [self CreateTable];
}

-(void)CreateTable
{
    pickerView.hidden=YES;
    done.hidden=YES;
    doneclicked.hidden=YES;
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [pickerView setDataSource: (id)self];
    [pickerView setDelegate: (id)self];
    [pickerView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
    pickerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    float  screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    pickerView.layer.cornerRadius=5;    // Set the picker's frame. We set the y coordinate to 50px.
    [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, screenWidth-200, 320.0, 180)];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [pickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    // OK, we are ready. Add the picker in our view.
    [self.view addSubview: pickerView];
    [cityalert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [statealert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    doneclicked = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    doneclicked .backgroundColor= [UIColor blackColor];
    [doneclicked setFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenWidth-200, 320, 30)];
    [doneclicked addTarget:self action:@selector(doneClickedpicker) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [doneclicked setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    doneclicked.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [self.view addSubview:doneclicked];
    [doneclicked setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    doneclicked.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 270, 0, 0);
    _datePickerView.hidden=YES;
    done.hidden=YES;
}
// not called these method
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}
  //  please help me
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask a better question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
            ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                if (!connectionError) {
    //enter code here
                  }
})];
```

and fetch response for that web service from the async thread.

In your code you have called urlconnection from thread and delegate on UI thread so That is creating issue. For Async call use above method else call that web service class from the UI/main thread. 
May be this can help you.

**EDIT*******
you can replace

```
-(void)callingStatelist{
     // code
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
}
```

Methods by

```
-(void)callingStatelist{

        @try {
            CheckConnection*obj=[[CheckConnection alloc]init];
            UrlService*objurlservice= [[UrlService alloc]init];
            [objurlservice url];

            [obj internet ];
            if (obj.conection==true) {
                NSString* soapMessage=  @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetStateList xmlns='http://tempuri.org'><webreq>%@</webreq></GetStateList></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
                // create a url to your asp.net web service.
                NSURL *tmpURl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",objurlservice.urlstring]];

                // create a request to your asp.net web service.
                NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tmpURl];

                // add http content type - to your request
                [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

                // add  SOAPAction - webMethod that is going to be called
                [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetStateList" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

                // count your soap message lenght - which is required to be added in your request
                NSString *msgLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];
                // add content length
                [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

                // set method - post
                [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                // set http request - body
                [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                // establish connection with your request & here delegate is self, so you need to implement connection's methods
                NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];


                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
                 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                     if (!connectionError) {

                         NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                         data = nil;

                         responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;"
                                                                                    withString:@">"];
                         responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;"
                                                                                    withString:@"<"];
                         NSData* data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                         NSLog(@"response%@",responseString);
                         responcearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                         parsar = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];
                         [parsar setDelegate: (id)self];
                         [parsar setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
                         [parsar parse];

                     }
                 })];
            }
            else{
                UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Smart24x7" message:@"Check your internet connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"exeption%@",exception);
        }

    }
```

Comment: currently you are using   `NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
            if(con)
            {
                responseData=[[NSMutableData data] init];
                // here -> NSMutableData *myWebData; -> declared in .h file     }
`
 Method. rather you can use above method to get web service response. which will work under the dispatch async.

Comment: actually when the picker creation method is called the compiler come back in his calling state